# Windows 7 boot error 0xc0000225 after falling down

Tags: windows-7, boot, repair

My Toshiba netbook fell down and hasn't booted again.  When I start Windows 7 it immediately says:

> Windows failed to start...
>   Status: 0xc0000225
>   Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.

After that, there are a few things to consider:

1. There's a Linux distro *Linkat* which is also installed in the computer.  It starts normally without any problem and it doesn't seem to display any errors when it boots.
2. I restored all computer OSs with clonezilla and some images provided by the manufacturer, and it's done nothing.
3. I have already checked the basic components of the PC (RAM, Hard Disk, WLAN Card) are pluged in and working.

My impression is that's all about some broken part inside, though the Linux OS starts normally.

Does anyone know a way I can fix this or at least any software for identifying the problem at all?

Comment: Instead of using Clonezilla and some image that may not be right for your notebook, have you tried (re)installing Windows from standard install media to see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found that the problem is the Hard Drive is damaged and some sectors are not working.  I changed the HDD  for another one with Windows installed and it started correctly.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Apply these tips to fix blue screen error:-

- Disconnect incompatible hardware.
- Check and repair disk errors.
- Perform System Clean-Up with Reginout or Ccleaner.
- Scan for Malicious Content.
- Run System File Check Up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked is the active partition is the correct one? [1]

Use `diskpart` to troubleshoot that. The commands are:

`diskpart` and then `list part`

You'll see a list of partition listed. If your active partition isn't correct, you can set the correct one with these commands:

`select partition x`

`active`

`quit`

Reboot.

[1] https://neosmart.net/wiki/0xc0000225/#Fix_2_Manually_configuring_the_active_partition